# Working with large offsets in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am trying to emulate pagination in BigQuery by grabbing a certain row number using an offset. It looks like the time to retrieve results steadily degrades as the offset increases until it hits `ResourcesExceeded` error. Here are a few example queries:

[image]

Is there a better way to use the equivalent of an "offset" with BigQuery without seeing performance degradation? I know this might be asking for a magic bullet that doesn't exist, but was wondering if there are workarounds to achieve the above. If not, if someone could suggest an alternative approach to getting the above (such as kinetica or cassandra or whatever other approach), that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify reasoning behind doing this from practical standpoint?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant an example would be a product catalog (~10M entries) where the user wants to scroll down to items starting with the letter "M". It's a task that I find myself doing daily in Excel (on spreadsheets about 500k-1M rows).

Comment: why not to use something like `WHERE LOWER(product_name) > 'm'`?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yes that would work, but I'm more describing a random seek pattern of behavior for the user on the front-end, for example what if they go to m, then z, then c, then a, etc. Or, if the field is a date-time field, would they have to type in the full date-time every time?

Comment: i would say  - it is up to app's UI to make users interaction with your app as friendly and comfortable as possible. so most likely - Yes - somehow user need to enter what they want to start with - this can be plain entry or some sort of calendar control - sorry if i am going wrong direction here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by Dan you need to introduce a row number. Now `row_number() over ()` exceeds resources. This basically means you have to split up the work of counting rows:

- decide for few and as evenly distributed partitions as possible
- count rows of each partition
- cumulative sum of partitions to know later when to start where with counting rows
- split up up work of counting rows
- save new table with row count column for later use

As partitions I used `EXTRACT(month FROM pickup_datetime)` as it distributes nicely

```sql
WITH
  temp AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    -- cumulative sum of partition sizes so we know when to start counting rows here
    SUM(COALESCE(lagged,0)) OVER (ORDER BY month RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cumulative
  FROM (
      -- lag partition sizes to next partition
    SELECT
      *,
      LAG(qty) OVER (ORDER BY month) lagged
    FROM (
        -- get partition sizes
      SELECT
        EXTRACT(month FROM pickup_datetime) month,
        COUNT(1) qty
      FROM
        `nyc-tlc.green.trips_2014`
      GROUP BY
        1)) )
SELECT
  -- cumulative sum = last row of former partition, add to new row count
  cumulative + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(month FROM pickup_datetime)) row,
  *
FROM
  `nyc-tlc.green.trips_2014`
-- import cumulative row counts
LEFT JOIN
  temp
ON
  (month= EXTRACT(month FROM pickup_datetime))
```

Once you saved it as a new table you can use your new row column to query without losing performance:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `project.dataset.your_new_table`
WHERE
  row BETWEEN 10000001
  AND 10000100
```

Quite a hassle, but does the trick.

Comment: very interesting and creative solution. Took > 100s to run when I tried it though, but yes it did work.

Comment: You mean table creation? One could make it faster with more partitions I guess. This should be scalable until you reach slots maximum.

Comment: looking into @David542 question and his comments to question and have hard time to see how this answer actually answers all of these. i might need to rest a little and get back here :o) anyway - good job - congrats with hefty bounty :o)

Comment: It's kind of a joint effort of me and Dan: while he explained why there is no good way to solve this because it goes beyond the purpose of bq - I delivered the hacky approach of introducing row numbers in case the table already exists. Since the approach is scalable and works I don't see why it wouldn't be a viable answer?!

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann - That's Ok. As long as OP think it answers his question - it is! I was just under impression (based on his statement - `but I'm more describing a random seek pattern of behavior for the user on the front-end, for example what if they go to m, then z, then c, then a, etc. Or, if the field is a date-time field ...`) that OP wanted something more generic and on fly (vs. pregenerated) which is obviously cannot be achieved . Anyway - great job :o)

Answer (score 7):

Offset in systems like BigQuery work by reading and discarding all results until the offset.

You'll need to use a column as a lower limit to enable the engine to start directly from that part of the key range, you can't have the engine randomly seek midway through a query efficiently.

For example, let's say you want to view taxi trips by rate code, pickup, and drop off time:

```
SELECT *
FROM [nyc-tlc:green.trips_2014]
ORDER BY rate_code ASC, pickup_datetime ASC, dropoff_datetime ASC
LIMIT 100
```

If you did this via OFFSET 100000, it takes 4s and the first row is:

```
pickup_datetime: 2014-01-06 04:11:34.000 UTC
dropoff_datetime: 2014-01-06 04:15:54.000 UTC
rate_code: 1
```

If instead of offset, I had used those date and rate values, the query only takes 2.9s:

```
SELECT *
FROM [nyc-tlc:green.trips_2014]
WHERE rate_code >= 1
  AND pickup_datetime >= "2014-01-06 04:11:34.000 UTC"
  AND dropoff_datetime >= "2014-01-06 04:15:54.000 UTC"
ORDER BY rate_code ASC, pickup_datetime ASC, dropoff_datetime ASC
limit 100
```

So what does this mean? Rather than allowing the user to specific result # ranges (e.g, so new rows starting at 100000), have then specified it in a more natural form (e.g, so how rides that started on January 6th, 2015.

If you want to get fancy and REALLY need to allow the user to specific actual row numbers, you can make it a lot more efficient by calculating row ranges in advance, say query everything once and remember what row number is at the start of the hour for each day (8760 values), or even minutes (525600 values). You could then use this to better guess efficient start. Do a look-up for the closest day/minute for a given row range (e.g in Cloud Datastore), then convert that users query into the more efficient version above.

Comment: could you please give an example? Let's say there are two fields, `id` (auto-incrementing) and `bool` (true/false). What if a user wants to sort by bool desc, id asc and get the entries 150M-151M, how would they do that? ... This may be a trivial example, but suppose there is a complex sort of multiple columns added, how to use a column in a generalized way as a lower limit?

Comment: Sorry, did that on my phone before a soccer match. There isn't really an efficient way to get exact row numbers, unless you already have that as an explicit column, you have to pass it upon the columns you're querying against, such as auto ids after x

Comment: are there any plans in the future to allow arbitrary offsets in BQ without getting the resourceExceeded error?

Comment: am I the first person to request this feature or have others asked for something similar as well?

Answer (score 0):

Why not export the resulting table into GCS?

It will automatically split tables into files if you [use wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files), and this export only has to be done one time, instead of querying every single time and paying for all the processing.

Then, instead of serving the result of the call to the BQ API, you simply serve the exported files.

Comment: If there are more than 16,000 rows BigQuery won't be able to export it.