# Working with Large Offsets in BigQuery [part 2]

Tags: google-bigquery

This is a follow-up to this question, which has a valid answer: [Working with large offsets in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49077822/working-with-large-offsets-in-bigquery).

Is it possible to do arbitrary pagination if I add an auto-incrementing row, and always sort ASC by that at the end of the sort? For example:

```
select * from bq order by c0, c1, c2, id ASC limit 100 OFFSET 1e6
==> Convert it to a where clause
```

My thought was to use something like an euler method to approximate where the Nth entry would be based on the sort, but I think with arbitrary sorts this could possibly exhaust all bq resources (for example, what if there are other numeric all-distinct rows in the sort). Any ideas if this may be possible without saving a tmp table?

Comment: how this is different from your initial question? :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant adding in an autoincrementing row in the sort to perhaps help with generating a where clause instead of doing a huge offset.

Comment: _"but I think with arbitrary sorts this could possibly exhaust all bq resources"_ Why not just try it and see?